# Closure (JS) Iterators

Tags: javascript, iterator, google-closure

I'm having little issues with translating Python generator, into Google Closure iterator.

```
for n,nbrs in nodes_nbrs:
    for nbr,data in nbrs.items():
        yield (n, nbr, data)
```

I have following and stuck in it

```
var nodeNbrs = map(this.adj.getKeyIterator(), function(n) {
    return [n, this.adj.get(n)]
});
var iter = new Iterator;
iter.next = function() {
    // what do I do?
};
```

Comment: I don't know Python but is `goog.iter.toIterator` perhaps what you're looking for? `var iter = goog.iter.toIterator(nodeNbrs);` will return an full-featured iterator for the array.

Comment: The code above iterates over elements of a list, which itself is an element of another list. `nodeNbrs` is already an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

use two goog.structs.foreach inside each other

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_structs_structs.js.html